# Rewrite url for existing page without flush_rewrite_rules

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have created pages with slug `test123` and `test234` in wordpress, I want to create a plugin that doing the following

- when user request `test123`, and the content in `test234` will be served instead.

I understand I can use the rewrite API but it is possible to do so without the need of `flush_rewrite_rules`? That is, without setting the rules in database?

Comment: If you just want the `test123` page to display the *post content* of the `test234` page, you could simply use a shortcode or edit the page template to query and display the `test234` content? Why do you need the URL rewrite?

Comment: @SallyCJ because I have a lot of pages need to be rewrited at once. I would like to keep the mapping in a PHP file (that is my plugin) instead of flushing rewrite rules in db every-time I need to update.

Comment: In that case, you can try the `request` or `parse_request` hook..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to rewrite `example.com/test123` (a standard WordPress Page) to `example.com/test234` (another standard WordPress Page) *without* having to save the rewrite rules *in the database*, then one option is using the [`request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/request/) filter hook:

```php
add_filter( 'request', function ( $query_vars ) {
    if ( isset( $query_vars['pagename'] ) ) {
        $slug = $query_vars['pagename'];

        // Define a list of source and target Page slugs.
        $mapping = [
            'test123' => 'test234',
            'test567' => 'foo-bar',
            //...
        ];

        // If the requested slug is in the mapping list, change the requested page slug.
        if ( ! empty( $mapping[ $slug ] ) ) {
            $query_vars['pagename'] = $mapping[ $slug ];
        }
    }
    return $query_vars;
} );
```

You can also use the [`parse_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) action hook, but the above should be fine, so I'm not including the code for that action hook.

But whether you use the filter hook or the action hook, the trick is to internally change the requested page *slug* if it matches the source slug in the mapping list/array. That way, requesting (or visiting) `example.com/test123` is essentially the same as requesting `example.com/test234` where the HTTP headers and page header, content, footer, etc. would be the same.

Comment: Thanks, actually I am wondering if this work, why a lot of plugin developers still need to save rules on db..

Comment: Well, these are just my personal thoughts. 1) It's a standard practice where one would normally use `add_rewrite_rule()` which by default saves the rules in the database (the other option is, written to the `htaccess` file). 2) There would not be any necessity for the extra step where we alter the requested page slug after it was actually determined - WP does that by looping through the saved rewrite rules in the database.

Comment: (cont) 3) Maybe their rules are not constantly changing like yours, so they only need to flush the rules upon activation/deactivation of their plugin. Which means, you may programmatically flush the rules so long as it's done properly.. 4) They don't know about the trick mentioned in the answer.. or they just prefer writing the rules to the database..